# What regular expression can be used to match a word with a certain character at a certain point

Tags: python, regex

For example:

```
w for w in wordlist if re.search("..........")
```

Lets say you wanted an a in the second location and a b in the 5th location and you knew it was 8 characters long. Can you even do this with regex? Thanks.

Example input, lets say wordlist is only two words: [test][batpbuuu]

This regex would return batpbuuu because it has an a in the second spot and a b in the 5th.

Comment: Do you have an example input and also an expected output?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest `re.match` (with `'.a.{2}b.{3}'`) rather than `re.search` so it doesn't try to find those characters in the middle of the string, but it doesn't sound like you need a regex at all for this.

```
w for w in wordlist if len(w) == 8 and w[1] == 'a' and w[4] == 'b'
```

Comment: Yeah, of course what you did is simpler, regex isn't needed, but I would like to know how / if you could do it in regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can totally ensure that the 2nd character is a and the 5th character is b in regex. You don't even have to use regex for this but i'll show it anyway since that's what you asked.

Here's an example:

```
.a.{2}b
```

The first dot matches any character (except newline), next we match only an a, then we match any character (except newline) 2 times, then we match only if it has a b.

```
kallb #matches

ja78b #matches

ja99k #doesnt match (missing a b)

jkksb #doesnt match (missing an a)

kj912 #doesnt match (missing both)
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/wR6lR3/1

Comment: I believe it's `2` for the second `.`, not `3`, as the `b` should be the fifth character, not the sixth. And you don't need to use a range if you just want an exact number of repetitions.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks, you're right. I fixed them all.

Comment: @Racialz It doesn't yet check for the string to be 8 chars long.

Comment: @AKS he says `and you knew it was 8 characters long`. I don't think the question is asking how to validate that it's 8 characters long, just that he has strings of 8 characters that he wants to run the regex on

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
re.search(r'^.a.{2}b.{3}$', i)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> w = ['test', 'batpbuuu', 'foobar', 'aachbfoo55', 'laghb678']
>>> [i for i in w if re.search(r'^.a.{2}b.{3}$', i)]
['batpbuuu', 'laghb678']
```

Comment: If the eight-character length is a requirement (the question is ambiguous on that point), then this is the only correct answer so far.  But any answer that *doesn't* have a `^` at the beginning (or use the `match` method, which has the same effect) is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following for your requirement

```
re.search('.a..b...', word)
```

. signifies any character

a --> in second location

b ---> in the 5th locatoin

Comment: I think it's "and a `b` in the 5th location" rather than "and `ab` in the 5th location."

Comment: Do we need to specify (r'.a..b..') instead of ('.a..b..')? 

@heemayl , it is implicitly regex when we use re.search, right?

Comment: `re.search` is explicitly a function in the regular expression module (`re`). Prepending a string with `r` is only necessary if we'll be using backslashes in the expression and want to specify a raw string to avoid having to escape the backslashes.